# How to integrate paypal with angular 2+?

Tags: angular, paypal

Is there a way to integrate paypal services to angular 2+ application? I couldn't find any resources in the official paypal documentation. Can someone point me to a good resource to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use this [service](https://auth0.com/authenticate/angular2/paypal/).

You could install it with yarn:

> yarn add auth0-js

or also with npm:

> npm install --save auth0-js

After that you add this lines to your base code

```
// src/app/app.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {
    auth.handleAuthentication();
  }

}
```

*HTML*

```
<!-- src/app/app.component.html -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Auth0 - Angular</a>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-margin" routerLink="/">Home</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-margin" *ngIf="!auth.isAuthenticated()" (click)="auth.login()">Log In</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-margin" *ngIf="auth.isAuthenticated()" (click)="auth.logout()">Log Out</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<main class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

I hope i helped you.

Greetings Doggo

Comment: How is the status to this question?

Comment: is there a way to use paypal without Auth0 for angular 2+ apps ?

Comment: I think yes but unfortunately I didn't use any other services than Auth0. And I don't know any other services @AnuradhaGunasekara.

Comment: I would suggest you ask a new question and exclude auth0 from the question.